# Fitting an exponential function on gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have to fit a dataset to the function f(x) = B + f(0)*exp(-x/t)

I get an error saying 'undefined value during function evaluation'. I presume the error is in the following bit of code:

```
f0 = 9444
f(x)= b + f0*exp(-x/t)
fit f(x) 'dataset.txt' using 2 : 3 via b,t
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with this code. Probably something together with the data. Maybe start with `reset session` and then try to post a MRE together with minimal data such that we can reproduce it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Probably the search for values of `t` hit t=0 and evaluation failed on a divide-by-zero error.

Try setting `f(x) = b + f0 * exp(-x*t)` instead.  You can invert t after finding a solution.

However, if you are describing exponential decay as a function of time *t* then you have your variable names confusingly reversed.  The more conventional way of writing this would be

```
 f(t) = b + f0 * exp(-x*t)
```